# What tools should every home mechanic have?

Tags: tools

What tools should every home mechanic have in their toolbox?  One item per answer please, upvote the best ones.  This is intended to be a wiki-style question.

Comment: Please see http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/3/making-a-site-for-professionals

Comment: A big roll of duct tape.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend a few items

- A spanner set with open and closed heads
- ViseGrip
- 1/4" and 1/2" socket wrench sets

In my experience the sizes I use most are 8mm, 9mm, 10mm, 14mm, 15mm, 17mm and the inches equivelants